# Docusign Interface from ERP #DocuSignAPI

Tags: api, pdf, docusignapi, erp

Hy,

i looked over the Docusign API.
But i already have some questions. 
Here my situation:

- We use Odoo (Openerp8) as ERP System in my Company.
- In the Future we wan't that the clients sign offers with docusign.

And here is my Problem:

- In the Future, the Salesmen should create a Offer in our ERP System, then he should trigger a action, ERP calls DocuSign API.

It should fill out a PDF Template and sends the PDF to the client, which is given to docusign over the API Call. 
Our Offer PDF have some placeholders which should filled out by the API Call?

Is a complex API call like this possible?

And the next question, what happens if the client has signed the document. 
Is it possible that my ERP System gets the information,  that the client has signed the document? Maybe it sends a copy to a email box which will fetched per ERP.
Because After the client has signed the Document, my ERP should start the Onboarding.

Hope the first and / or the second question is possible 
with the docusign api
Thanks
Ghovat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Before You Begin

First off I'd contact Odoo and see if they have a plan to integrate with DocuSign in the near future. I don't see them listed on the [DocuSign Partner's Solution Showcase](https://www.docusign.com/partners/solution-showcase), but it doesn't mean they haven't already invested the foot work into building the base functionality of what you want.

---

## From A DocuSign API Perspective

### Question 1:

> It should fill out a PDF Template and sends the PDF to the client,
>   which is given to docusign over the API Call. Our Offer PDF have some
>   placeholders which should filled out by the API Call?

Yes this is possible through the API. The easiest way to resolve this is to create a DocuSign template and use that on sending, and fill the form values dynamically if the data comes from outside of the PDF, or convert form fields if the information is inside the PDF.

Example code to look at: [DocuSign API Walkthroughs - Request Signature via Template](http://iodocs.docusign.com/apiwalkthroughs)

### Question 2:

> And the next question, what happens if the client has signed the
>   document. Is it possible that my ERP System gets the information, that
>   the client has signed the document?

The advised way of handling this is setting up a Connect Listener, and DocuSign will push notifications (based on your Connect setting parameters). You would likely host this on your own server somewhere, and have ERP ping the server for updates.

Alternatively you can have your system fetch status and update depending on the response. You want to be careful with this one and ensure that you're meeting the requirements of the DocuSign API Certification Checklist.

---

Quoted from [DocuSign API Developer Center - API Best Practices](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/go-live/certification)

> Additionally, your API certification review involves verifying that
>   you do not exceed 1 status request per unique envelope per 15 minutes
>   for polling compliance for the following methods:
>
> **SOAP API:**
>   RequestStatus, RequestStatusEx, RequestStatuses, RequestStatusesEx,
>   RequestPDF and RequestDocumentPDFs.
>
> **REST API:** GET
>   /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes